# regexp_substr oracle function conversion to pyspark

Tags: oracle, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert existing Oracle sql which is using in-built function `regexp_substr` into pyspark sql. 
This oracle sql is taking user input value and applying regexp_substr function to get the required output string.

Example - 1BBC string below is the user input value

`1. select nvl(regexp_substr('1BBC', 'BBB\+|BBB|CCC|AAA|BB|CC|AA|B|A|C'), 'XYZ') from dual`

`Output -`
`BB`

`2. BBB++ string below is the user input value
select nvl(regexp_substr('BBB++', 'BBB\+|BBB|CCC|AAA|BB|CC|AA|B|A|C'), 'XYZ') from dual`

`Output -`
`BBB+`

Is there any way to achieve similar output using pyspark sql or dataframe operations?

Comment: use regexp_extract(), add capturing group to the pattern: `spark.sql("select regexp_extract('1BBC', '(BBB\\\\+|BBB|CCC|AAA|BB|CC|AA|B|A|C)', 1)")`.

Comment: Thanks can this be achieved using pandas as well ?

Comment: use extract: `s.str.extract('(BBB\+|BBB|CCC|AAA|BB|CC|AA|B|A|C)')` where `s = pd.Series(['1BBC', 'BBB++'])` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Comment: Works fine, thanks once again !